# jQuery, Expected identifier, string or number in IE6 and 7

Tags: jquery

I have an issue in IE6 and 7 where I am making an ajax request. The error is: `Expected identifier, string or number` on line 262 which is pointing to:

```
$("#submitNewAdmin").live('click',function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/ajax/ajax_new_admin.php",
        data:{
            username:$(".pp_inline #username").val(),
            password1:$(".pp_inline #password1").val(),
            password2:$(".pp_inline #password2").val(),
            email:$(".pp_inline #email").val(),
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            if (msg == "success")
            {
                location.reload(true);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the line where `success` takes place. I've googled around and the solutions to other peoples issues are that they had an extra comma. I have looked over my code and I cannot find an extra comma..can anyone see anything I am doing wrong? All of this code is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Also, I am using `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

Comment: you have an extra COMMA at the end of your data object, after `email:$(".pp_inline #email").val()`

Comment: I guess looking at the same code over and over its easy to overlook things...that WAS the problem..thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the extra comma (and yes, it will certainly cause you problems in IE):

```
    data:{
        username:$(".pp_inline #username").val(),
        password1:$(".pp_inline #password1").val(),
        password2:$(".pp_inline #password2").val(),
        email:$(".pp_inline #email").val(), // <----
    },
```

Running your code through a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) would generate an error like this:

> Problem at line 10 character 47: Unexpected ','.

Comment: ah I dont know how I missed that..ugh...that JSLint tool looks like it can come in handy. I will accept your answer when it allows me